# How to fix torn EV3 LCD Cable

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, electronics

I accidentally tore my lego EV3's LCD ribbon cable while opening it.
I found [this post](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/18003/lego-mindstorms-ev3-broken-screen-cable) of someone a while back having the same issue, however as my tear is smaller I was wondering if it was possible to fix it:
[image: Image of torn 18-pin ribbon cable]

Nothing has been taken away from the cable, and the torn part still fits in with the rest.

Comment: Repairing a flat ribbon is tricky. And since it's not lego-specific, I suggest asking at electronics.stackexchange.com .

Comment: @IvanSanchez i made a post and people were very helpful, and now I have a few paths to attempt. How could I close this question?
Funny that the original answered (you) to the question i referenced also answered this!